# regex excluding a char before a symbol in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently want to make the first letter of a city name uppercase; but since in my country we have a lot of cities with a multiple words composed name (eg. New York), i am currently using this regex:

`/\w\S*/g`

so I am using this function

```
function capitalizeWords(myString) {
  return myString.replace(/\w\S*/g, w => w.replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase()))
}
```

so I can change `new york`in `New York`.

But now I have a small issue, I have some cities like

`sauze d'oulx`

and I need to convert it to `Sauze d'Oulx`, excluding the `d`, or in any case the first character before the `'` symbol.

What is the trick to exclude one char before a known one?

Comment: Exclude the quote from your character class. However, I doubt you will handle all the edge cases like that, senior Zorro.

Comment: If there are any other edge cases, please include them.

Comment: Thanks :D I'm thinking about it, the only other edge cases could be to exclude the last word of no more than 2 chars before a space, eg. `bagno di romagna` becomes `Bagno di Romagna`, but I think it's a completely different regex

Comment: Actually there are a lot of edge cases [List of double placenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_double_placenames)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define all your exceptions as alternatives before matching and capturing your expected match:

```js
const texts = ["new york", "sauze d'oulx"];
const capitalizeWords = (myString) =>
  myString.replace(/\bd['’]|(\w)(\S*)/g, (m, g, h) => g ? g.toUpperCase() + h : m);
  
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '->', capitalizeWords(text));
}
```

The `\bd['’]|(\w)(\S*)` regex matches

- `\bd['’]` - a `d'` or `d’` after a non-word char or at the start of string
- `|` - or
- `(\w)(\S*)` - a word char captured into Group 1 (`g` in the code above) and then zero or more non-whitespaces into Group 2 (`h` in the code above).

The `(m, g, h) => g ? g.toUpperCase() + h : m` replacement means that the replacement is the match itself if Group 1 did not match, else, the char matched with `\w` is capitalized.

Extending with `di` preposition:

```js
const texts = ["new york", "sauze d'oulx", "bagno di romagna"];
const capitalizeWords = (myString) =>
  myString.replace(/\bd(?:['’]|i\b)|(\w)(\S*)/g, (m, g, h) => g ? g.toUpperCase() + h : m);
  
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '->', capitalizeWords(text));
}
```